# Receive emails on my website/domain from all other domains

Tags: php, email, dns

As per the requirement of my client, I need to receive emails on my website from all other domains like gmail , hotmail , yahoo etc.Like receive emails on "myname@mywebsite.com" from any domain.

Is there any way to do so in PHP? Any word from you will be a great help

Comment: You need `sendmail` to do local delivery if that's what you mean. What do you want to do with the received emails?

Comment: There are many possibilities how to solve this requirement using php. What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: You can't receive emails on a "website", only on a mail server. You could have a web application that acts as an email client though. PHP could be used to write an SMTP server and a web based email client (although it wouldn't be my first choice for either) but that is far too big a problem to be answered on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could do this with PHP alone, that wouldn't be a good idea.  If you need to receive emails to your domain, there are two ways of going about it:

1. Local `sendmail`: you need a server with open port 25; you'll need to configure MX records in DNS and properly configure your sendmail to avoid all sorts of security issues.  You could, of course, write an SMTP server in PHP, but I wouldn't recommend it.
2. SAAS approach (e.g. google apps is one example).  If you don't need to more than a handful of users, then google apps is free to use and is very easy to set up.  Google doesn't tell you any more that they have a free version - they want some money from you, namely $50 per user per year, but if you go to this page directly: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/standard/new3 - it apparently still allows you to sign in.  There are other providers of hosted email - try search the web for it.